# No error is displayed if actual result does not match expected result while login to application using selenium java

Tags: java, selenium, authentication

In below script, if actual result does not match expected result, no error is shown. If actual result  match expected result the it returns "errors in login". How to handle this?

```
   try
    {
                try 
                {
                    String errormsg  = loginpage.errormsg.getText();
                    String invalidstring = loginpage.invalidstring.getText();
                    String strActualResult=errormsg.replace(invalidstring, ""); 
                    if(strActualResult.trim().equalsIgnoreCase(strExpectedResult))
                    {
                        System.out.println("Error in login");
                        config.writetoexcel(projectPath,sheetName,1,3,"Pass");
                        
                    }
                }
                catch(Exception e)
                {
                    if(lp.isDisplayed())
                    {
                        System.out.println("Login successfull");
                        config.writetoexcel(projectPath,sheetName,1,3,"Pass");
                    }   
                }
    }
    catch(Exception e)
    {
        System.out.println("Error: "+e.getMessage());
        config.writetoexcel(projectPath,sheetName,1,3,"Fail");
        config.writetoexcel(projectPath,sheetName,1,4,e.getMessage());      
    }
```

Comment: have you debugged the test, to check whether the result is what you assume it is?

Comment: seems like you don't need a try/catch there but a simple if/else... include your loginpage class.

Comment: it didn't work without try/catch. I used else condition after if(strActualResult.trim().equalsIgnoreCase(strExpectedResult)) and it worked. Thanks